# How to fix UnsatisfiedLinkError when loading a NDK-generated library in an Eclipse-based Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I've got an Android project set up for Eclipse (Juno).

The project relies on a native library called `synth`, which is generated via `ndk-build` on the command line, which creates the various `libsynth.so` files for each different architecture within the `libs` folder, e.g. `libs/armeabi/libsynth.so` etc.

The library is loaded in code as follows:

```
System.loadLibrary("synth");
```

This line crashes at runtime:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load foo from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader...
```

It seems the `.so` files are there but aren't getting linked in. How to I tell Eclipse to link that library when exporting the Android package? Or is there something else I should be doing to fix this?

Full stack trace:

> E/AndroidRuntime(18030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030): Process: com.levien.synthesizer, PID: 18030
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load synth from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.levien.synthesizer-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.levien.synthesizer-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at com.levien.synthesizer.android.AndroidGlue.(AndroidGlue.java:51)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at com.levien.synthesizer.android.service.SynthesizerService.onCreate(SynthesizerService.java:88)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18030):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 1. Post entire stacktrace. 2. Post JNI code.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - stack trace posted. Don't think JNI code is problem as this was working fine before I re-imported the project into new Eclipse workspace, which is why I think it's a config issue with Eclipse. But can post that code too if you still think it would be helpful.

Comment: You said you `re-imported` back in to Eclipse? From Android Studio? What do you mean? Also are you only building for one arch: `armeabi`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows - sorry, that wasn't clear. What I did was this: I created a new Eclipse workspace. Then imported the existing Android project. Now when I export the APK, I get this runtime error. The only thing that has changed is the different Eclipse workspace, which suggests to me I need to "tell" Eclipse to link that library somehow.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - the .so files for all the architectures are there in the different subfolders until `libs` -- not sure if Eclipse is building for just one architecture or all -- how do I check?

Comment: You would have to setup eclipse to build with the ndk. I usually just build via command line. Based on the `findLibrary returned null ` it is simply not finding your lib. Are you using `Gradle` to build your project in `Eclipse`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows - how can I tell if it is using `Gradle`? (You can tell I'm an Eclipse/Android noob.) What I do to create the APK is right-click the project, go to Android Tool, then Export Signed Application Package...

Comment: Forget I asked that. You need to figure out why it is not finding the `.so` before you can export your app.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - I'm not sure, but I don't *think* this it's using gradle. This is the old Eclipse way of building Android projects, before Android Studio. (I'm working with a legacy project that was created in Eclipse.)

Comment: @JaredBurrows - indeed, that's what I was trying to ask in my question -- how to get Eclipse to find that .so file.

Comment: It's hard to debug something when you do not post any code.

Comment: Open an ADB shell, and try `ls -l /data/app-lib/com.levien.synthesizer-1` on your device. This directory is usually readable for everybody. If `libsynth.so` is not there, check the contents of your APK (with your favourite ZIP viewer).

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows -- in the end I just started with a fresh Eclipse workspace, imported the Android project into that workspace, and it worked -- no linking problems. Maybe one of these days I'll learn how Eclipse works. For now, it's a non-deterministic mystery to me.

Comment: @AlexCohn - thanks. Yeah, I knew the .so wasn't getting linked -- thus the question of how to get Eclipse to link it. In the end, starting with a fresh workspace solved the problem. Unsatisfying solution, as I don't know what was wrong when I did the same thing before, but that's that.

Comment: @Ghopper21 good! post your answer of your debugging steps with Eclipse.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - afraid it really wasn't anything more than simple starting with a fresh workspace. Not even confident that works consistently, since the first time I did that (before asking this question), it didn't work. A mystery.